# Unable to initialize WebGL in Android Instant Game ("WebGL1 blacklisted")

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview, webgl, android-instant-apps

I'm developing an android instant game utilising a WebView (wrapped with Cordova). The game works well in a browser, and also as an installed app, and even through a WebView inside Facebook Messenger. However as an Android instant app initialising the WebGL context fails and I find this error in the log:

> 04-20 14:38:43.833 16769 16848 E chromium: [ERROR:context_group.cc(145)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: WebGL1 blacklisted

The device I've tried is Huawei MediaPad T3 10. I don't know if other devices work (I don't have any available at the moment). Some other instant games work with the device, but then again they probably don't use a WebView.

I've tried initialising WebGL2 if WebGL1 is blacklisted but that didn't work, probably for many reasons.

Why is the device blacklisted only in Android Instant Apps? Is there any way to circumvent the issue? Can I somehow whitelist the device?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the device some GLES feature support status caused webkit blacklist it. It's better to try on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old topic, but I ran in to this as well. Just try a newer Android image in your emulator. It may work on real hardware, but not the emulator.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37129533?pli=1